# Getting wrong output in xls/xlsx while converting it from csv

Tags: spring, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

So i've changed a csv to xls/xlsx but i'm getting one character per cell. I've used pipe(|) as a delimiter in my csv. 
Here is one line from the csv:
4.0|sdfa@sdf.nb|plplplp|plplpl|plplp|1988-11-11|M|asdasd@sdf.ghgh|sdfsadfasdfasdfasdfasdf|asdfasdf|3.4253242E7|234234.0|true|true|

But in excel i'm getting as
4 . 0 | s d f a

Here's the code:

```
    try {
        String csvFileAddress = "manage_user_info.csv"; //csv file address
        String xlsxFileAddress = "manage_user_info.xls"; //xls file address
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
        String currentLine=null;
        int RowNum=0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileAddress));
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = currentLine.split("|");
            RowNum++;
            HSSFRow currentRow=sheet.createRow(RowNum);
            for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
                currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(str[i]);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =  new FileOutputStream(xlsxFileAddress);
        workBook.write(fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+"Exception in try");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe symbol must be escaped in a regular expression:

```java
String str[] = currentLine.split("\\|");
```

It is a logical operator (quote from the [Javadoc of java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

> X|Y   Either X or Y

Comment: @ASHWANI This answer has been the accepted answer before, now it has been unaccepted. But I do not see a reason for it (like wrong answer, a better answer whatever)?